# Замена (Sensor.TYPE_Proximity); на (Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT); перестал гаснуть экран

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

На новых девайсах, где используется приложение, изменился сенсор на сенсор освещенности:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensorProximity = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
```

Приложение настроено так, что если `Sensor.TYPE_Proximity` закрыт, то экран гаснет.

Тип сенсора поменял на `Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT`. Все работает, но когда сенсор закрыт экран не гаснет. Как я понимаю, за это отвечает:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Запущено приложение: " + RESTAURANT);
mTracker.setScreenName(RESTAURANT);
mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
try {
// Yeah, this is hidden field.
    field = PowerManager.class.getClass().getField("PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK").getInt(null);
    } catch (Throwable ignored) {
}

powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(field, getLocalClassName());
setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте организовать код, так чтобы он был для вас в первую очередь читаемым и понятным. Перенесите работу сенсора в отдельные методы, так будет проще ориентироваться. Поймайте момент, когда нужно дективировать [сенсор](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767115/unregisterlistener-doesnt-work-with-proximity-screen-off-wake-lock).